# Different SPF Check result

Tags: dns, spf

I tried to add spf record on my domain name.

I tried on two different domain and it return different result when I tried to check it using checkmx apps (https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/).

The first domain return :
[image: spf check on first domain]

The second domain return :
[image: spf check on second domain]

I wonder if the spf setting on both domain is good or not.
Anybody know what is the different between first and the second result?

Thank you.

**Edited**

Here are my spf records.

```
mydomain.com.au.mydomain.com.au. 900 IN TXT v=spf1 include:sparkpostmail.com
mydomain.com.au. 3600 IN TXT v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two different things. The first one tells you what IP ranges your whole SPF record covers, including any IPs pulled in via `include` mechanisms.

The second says that you have allowed google to send email on your behalf by deferring to their SPF record with an `include` mechanism in your SPF record.

You can easily have the first without the second; we can't tell you what you're doing wrong (if anything) without seeing the records themselves, and it depends what you're trying to do – for example if you *don't* want google to send mail for you, then including their SPF would be an error.

### Update for provided SPF records.

Those SPF records are strange - why do you have the one with the repeated domain? Did you forget a trailing `.` or something? I think you need to combine the two and your SPF should look like this:

```
mydomain.com.au. 900 IN TXT v=spf1 include:sparkpostmail.com include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

It is relatively unusual not to include an `mx` SPF mechanism (i.e. say that your *inbound* mail server is also allowed to *send* mail for your domain), but that's not unexpected if you're using gmail to handle your domain as it's covered by their `include`.

Comment: Hi @Synchro thanks for your answer.
Actualy I want to setup DMARC to manage suspicious emails.

Comment: OK, but you need to get SPF and DKIM working before you can use DMARC

Comment: Hi @Synchro thanks for your answer.
Actually I want to set up DMARC to manage suspicious emails.

So I think I must change my first SPF DNS record to make it pass "SPF must allow Google servers ..."

I have two spf records.

mydomain.com.au.mydomain.com.au. 900 IN TXT 
v=spf1 include:sparkpostmail.com

mydomain.com.au. 3600 IN TXT 
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all

Is there something that I need to change to make it pass the  "SPF must allow Google servers ..." check?

Comment: You can only have one SPF record. You can have multiple include mechanisms in that record, though you need to keep an eye on lookup count limits. It would help if you put your SPF records in your question – the formatting in comments isn't very good.

Comment: hi @Synchro
I've put it on my question. Thank you.

Comment: It is work now..
Actualy I am using gmail to handle my domain.
Thanks a lot @Synchro

Comment: Great. Please mark my answer as a solution to your question.